# Distance in KMs results are off - what am I doing wrong? PHP

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, geocode

So I am trying to get the distance between two point based on Latitude and Longitude calculated and printed to the screen, it 'works' but the correct answer is way off. And by way off I mean 187 kms off in my particular case. I am not sure why, and I feel as though I am doing something really silly but I can't seem to locate the problem. Here's what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Calculates Geographical Distance from Latitude and Longitude Pairs
 * 
 * @param array $pair1 Array of first Pair
 * @param array $pair2 Array of second Pair
 * 
 * @return string
 */
private function _calculateGeographicalDistanceFromLatLng($pair1, $pair2)
{
    $pi80  = M_PI / 180;
    $pair1[0] *= $pi80;
    $pair1[1] *= $pi80;
    $pair2[0] *= $pi80;
    $pair2[1] *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $pair2[0] - $pair1[0];
    $dlng = $pair2[1] - $pair1[1];
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($pair1[0]) * cos($pair2[0]) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c / 1000;

    if ($this->_unit == "all") {
        $miles = $km * 0.621371192;
        return array("KM" => round($km, 2), "Mile" => round($miles, 2));
    } elseif ($this->_unit == "mile") {
        $miles = $km * 0.621371192;
        return round($miles, 2);
    } else {
        return round($km, 2);
    }
}
```

When I try and have it echo the correct answer with different options, the answer is absolutely way off.

```
$df = new distanceAdvice("Geographic");
$result = $df->findDistance(array("53.219383", "6.566502"),    array("52.090737", "5.121420"));
if (isset($result['error'])) {
echo $result['error']['msg'];
} else {
echo "The geographical distance between the two points based on Latitude and Longitude is: " . $result . " Kilometer.<br />";
}
```

Comment: What is the answer you are getting that is "way off"?  What do you believe the correct answer is?  How are you checking its "correctness"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your pain about this.  I've had to encode this great circle distance formula into Excel VBA for some NASA geolocation work I've volunteered for.  There is confusing information about the proper formula to use on the web when you do a google search.  There is the Haversine formula, and the Spherical Law of Cosines formula.  Also, the ATAN2 formula is implemented slightly differently at times [some libraries do atan2(dy, dx) while other libraries (like Excel) do atan2(dx, dy]].

For the Haversine formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), try changing the line below.  The Haversine formula is not supposed to use ATAN2, and unfortunately some first results on Google searches provide the wrong formula:

```
$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
```

with

```
$c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
```

That is the proper Haversine formula.  There may be an edge case that needs to be accounted for ... my formula in Excel included:

```
 $c = 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt($a)));
```

And a source for that came from the U.S. Census (though its link is no longer valid) so here is a posting that references it:
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/visual/home/proj/tiger/gisfaq.html

Also, different distance calculators you will find online use different Earth radius values, since the earth is actually not round; even the term "sea level" is not consistent and "round" across the entire Earth.  So you may still find your distance calculation is slightly different from whatever you are using as a reference just because of different Earth radius values.

Comment: My Gosh, this totally did the job perfectly :-) Thank you so much.. Saved me so much time. I was already wondering if I had gone crazy

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance), to calculate distance between 2 points you should use `computeDistanceBetween(LatLngFrom, LatLngTo)`

Google handled all those `Mercator Projection` stuff for you so I guess, rather than writing your own, you should use this API.